# I am recieving an 'Invalid Source Folder' error in vs code when trying to export my javadoc comments

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, javadoc

When I try an export the javadoc comments from my java program this error pops up and I do not really know how to change the source folder or where to change the extension setting within vs code.

OS windows 11

tyring tp generate an html file, is it even possible in vs code?

Comment: what exactly are you doing to try to export the javadoc comments?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)